# Use `kubectl` from "asdf" instead of "homebrew"

Tags: macos, path, homebrew, kubectl, asdf

I have had `kubectl` installed from `homebrew` in mac since a long time. So from my *path*, the **homebrew kubectl** is used.

Today I installed `kubectl` using `asdf` to be able to use different versions of `kubectl` for different projects. However, my mac still sees the `kubectl` path from my `homebrew` installation - not the one from my new `asdf` installation.

How do I run the `kubectl` command and make it use the **asdf** version instead of using the **homebrew** version ?

Answer (score 7):

#### UPDATED ANSWER:

Added the following line into my **~/.zshrc** file

```sh
echo -e "\n. $(brew --prefix asdf)/libexec/asdf.sh" >> ${ZDOTDIR:-~}/.zshrc
```

Source: http://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf

---

#### OLD ANSWER BELOW

Asked too soon. Searched a bit more and found this blog which helped. https://migueldavid.eu/using-multiple-versions-of-kubectl-on-macos

The ASDF installations are made available through the `~/.asdf/shims` folder. As long as this directory is added into your `$PATH`, and as long as this path comes **BEFORE** the others, it will respect the installations via ASDF (if any) before the installations via Homebrew.

I added the following line in my `~/.zshrc` file

```sh
export PATH=$HOME/.asdf/shims:$PATH
```